# How to click on an element which contains text with seleniumbase?

Tags: python, selenium, seleniumbase

I have the following very short code where I expect to be able to click on a button which contains the text `Click Me`:

```
from seleniumbase import BaseCase

class MyTestClass(BaseCase):
    def test_basics(self):
        url = "https://seleniumbase.io/demo_page"
        self.open(url)
        self.click_partial_link("Click Me")
```

But it does not work. I get an error `NoSuchElementException`.
Documentation is [HERE](https://seleniumbase.io/help_docs/method_summary/).

So how to click on that button using `SeleniumBase` (https://seleniumbase.io/)?

Comment: What do you mean by Selenium Base?

Comment: https://seleniumbase.io/

Comment: looks like a library to me, I will see if I can learn and answer this question

Comment: Can you try out the below answer given by me and update me in case of any issues that you face ?

Comment: @cruisepandey Sorry, but I NEED to select on partial text only. So how to do that on this example page?

Comment: I think you can't achieve this by `partial_link_text`, see selenium doc basic about `partial_link_text` https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-hyperlinks-by-link-text

Answer (score 2):

The selector you're looking for is `'button:contains("Click Me")'`:

```py
self.click('button:contains("Click Me")')
```

There are more examples of the SeleniumBase `:contains()` selector here: https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/examples/test_contains_selector.py

It's not a standard CSS Selector, as it's specific to SeleniumBase, jQuery, and a few other places, but not everywhere.

Answer (score -1):

try xpath : `//*[text()='your text']`

Comment: Sorry, that does not work for me when I use `//*[text()='Click Me']`. I beleive it is because I am trying to select on a *partial* text.